# Joomla LMS solutions

Tags: extensions

I've been tasked with creating a site. A large part of the site's functionality will be in the form of online learning courses (mainly in SCORM format).

My original thought was to use a dedicated LMS product such as Moodle for this, but the site also needs to have a fair bit of CMS-type functionality that doesn't really suit Moodle. So I've changed tack, and I'm now thinking about a CMS like Joomla with some kind of LMS module or possibly integration with Moodle.

So my question is, what solutions exist for this kind of setup in the Joomla ecosystem?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/lms-king) and [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/lms-lite)

Comment: @Lodder: thanks for the reply. Do you have any experience with using these extensions? What are they like to use?

Comment: I've no idea. I've never been involved in using LSM's. The first link is the Pro version which has good ratings and reviews. The second link is the free/lite version so I'd suggest installing it on a Joomla instllation and testing it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to use the best of Joomla and the best of Moodle, then Joomdle is your answer. It takes some setup, so it's not for the faint of heart, but I've built 2 sites like this and helped someone build a 3rd, and it's been great.

In my case, I hid Moodle entirely so it was ONLY visible in the joomla container, and if you like nice things, you'll use something like Jomsocial or EasySocial which lets you ignore the Moodle user profiles and uses their (much fancier) profiles instead.

If you don't need the full features of Moodle, then one of the native LMS options would also work. There's a new one on the block now, though it's not in final release. It's called Shika. It has a nice drag and drop editor, but it's not anywhere close to Moodle's complete feature set. It's also fairly expensive.

[Joomdle Site](http://www.joomdle.com)

[Shika page on TechJoomla.com](https://techjoomla.com/products/shika.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As per my own answer, I had already discovered Joomdle and have been trying it out, but it's good to get some feedback from someone who's had a bit more exposure to it. My task for the time being was to do a technical evaluation; I've created a test site using Joomdle and have proven that it works and does what it promises. As you say, the setup was a bit complex, but overall my evaluation has gone well and we like what we see, so if the full project goes ahead we will be using Joomdle for it. If so, I may be back to ask more questions! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

@Lodder provided the following links in a comment:

- [LMS King](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/lms-king)
- [LMS Lite](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/lms-lite)

Thank you to Lodder for the links.

In addition to these, my own research has led me to [Joomdle](http://www.joomdle.com/), which is a package integrating Joomla and Moodle.